# Svelte invalidate() not refreshing after initial refresh

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a button on a Svelte page listing some data.  This button invokes a data endpoint to add/update a record to the database.  After the database is updated, the Svelte function invalidate('URL') gets called to refresh the page.  This works perfectly the first time the button is clicked, however, on subsequent clicks, the page does not get refreshed.  Is there an additional step I need to do to allow the invalidate() function to work on subsequent calls?  NOTE:  If I click on the browser's reload button, all of the data will appear which tells me that the data is getting updated everytime the button is clicked.

Comment: Am using location.reload(); for now which works but would still like to know why invalidate() doesn't work on subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

[`invalidate`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-invalidate) is for fine-grained dependency management that requires that you use `fetch` or `depends` on the passed URL.

Can't tell what exactly is wrong without seeing all of the relevant code, but in most cases that is not what you want anyway, instead just use [`invalidateAll`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-invalidateall).

Also: If you use the [`enhance` action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance) with [form actions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions), which is recommend, this will happen automatically already.